# Drag & Drop em qualquer posição na div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como faço para que o elemento que será "droppado" possa ficar em qualquer lugar na minha div? A maneira com que estou fazendo faz com que os elementos sejam alinhados.

Segue imagem e código até o momento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
```

```css
#etiqueta {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#toolbox {
    
  width: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  position: absolute;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="toolbox">
<ul>
    <label id ="lblDesc" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">@Descrição</label>
    <label id ="lblPrec" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">@Preço</label>
   <label id ="lblSku" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">@Sku</label>
</ul>
</div>    

<div id="etiqueta" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    
</div>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma das formas de fazer isso é utilizando o atributo `position: absolute` no seu *CSS*. Desta forma você poderá utilizar um valor fixo para posicionar seu elemento através das propriedade `left` e `top` do *CSS*. A desvantagem pode ocorrer quando a tela for redimensionada.

Para calcular e obter o valor da distância horizontal, utilizaremos a propriedade `clientX` do objeto `ev`. A propriedade `clientY` dará-nos a posição vertical do objeto.

Porém não é suficiente, isso porque o valor capturado será obtido com base no início do objeto (e não de onde foi clicado)

[image: Imagem de uma bola com a posição Y e X desenhada]

Para corrigimos esta falha, teremos que capturar a posição `X` e `Y` do objeto e subtrair com a posição `clientX` e `clientY`, respectivamente. Dessa forma iremos capturar, com mais precisão, o ponto inicial do clique do *mouse*.

Feito isso, basta capturarmos a posição final do *mouse* e subtrair com a diferença obtida acima.

Parece um pouco complicado, mas estarei deixando um código com a explicação do passo a passo.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  
  /* Armanezaremos as coordenadas do evento */
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("left", ev.clientX);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("top", ev.clientY);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  
  const clone = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true)
  clone.id = new Date().getMilliseconds()
  
  /**
   * Utilizamos esta função para capturar a posição
   * relativa do objeto ao viewport
   */
  const rect = document.getElementById(data).getBoundingClientRect()
  
  /**
   * Aqui, iremos obter a diferença entre a posição inicial
   * do mouse (ao ser pressionado) com a posição relativa
   * do objeto inicial.
   *
   * Este cálculo servirá para corrigir a posição final
   */
  let left = ev.dataTransfer.getData("left") - rect.left
  let top = ev.dataTransfer.getData("top") - rect.top
  
  /**
   * Finalmente iremos capturar a posição final do mouse
   * e corrigir com os valores acima
   */
  clone.style.left = `${ev.clientX - left}px`
  clone.style.top = `${ev.clientY - top}px`
  
  ev.target.appendChild( clone );
}
```

```css
#etiqueta {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#toolbox {
    
  width: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  position: absolute;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#etiqueta label { position: absolute }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="toolbox">
<ul>
    <label id ="lblDesc" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">@Descrição</label>
    <label id ="lblPrec" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">@Preço</label>
   <label id ="lblSku" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">@Sku</label>
</ul>
</div>    

<div id="etiqueta" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    
</div>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```